# How do I change my default browser?

Tags: default-browser

Is there an option to change my default browser for all my applications?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Have a look at your `system-settings` -> `Details`:

(Note that in older versions of Ubuntu `Details` is called `System Info`)

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty **stupid** place to put it! Almost as bad as having to go to "settings" to turn off your computer in Windows 8.

Comment: in ubuntu 14.04 [cinnamon theme] navigate to `System Settings > Preferred applications`

Comment: To launch this on Ubuntu 14.04 from the CLI try `unity-control-center` http://askubuntu.com/questions/116655/what-is-the-command-to-run-system-settings-from-a-terminal

Comment: How do I make an application show up in there?

Comment: To access this from CLI use `gnome-control-center` and go to `System > Details`. You will **also** need to use `update-alternatives` from Sergey P. aka azure's answer below, since different programs reads settings from different sources.

Comment: I cannot find it in Lubuntu 20_04

Comment: In german: 'Vorgabeanwendungen'

Answer (score 68):

This is an ubuntu way of doing this

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
```

Comment: This is a system-wide change, and should be done in addition to fossfreedom's answer.

Comment: I tried all the answers here; only the second of these two lines changed the browser in which browser-external links (e.g. from Pidgin) opened.

Comment: This is the most appropriate way to do this, working for i3WM and other desktop environments where terminals rules. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: This didn't work for me on ubuntu 16.04 (was trying to change the browser used by thunderbird to open links). The accepted solution worked.

Comment: Actually it's the Debian way.... "The Debian alternatives system was originally created for Debian but has been picked up by other GNU/Linux software distributions." https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives

Answer (score 64):

If your preferred browser isn't in that menu or you prefer doing it from the command line, this command will let you do the same thing as in fossfreedom's answer:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser name-of-browser.desktop
```

E.g.:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox.desktop
```

or

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser chromium-browser.desktop
```

or

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser google-chrome.desktop
```

Comment: For SEO reasons: this works with i3wm when chrome sneaks into `x-www-browser` and  `update-alternatives` is out of reach because it requires `sudo`. You need to have `my-application.desktop` available, for example in `~/.local/share/applications/my-app.desktop`. But you don't pass the entire path to `xdg-settings`, only the file name.

Comment: This is the right solution. It works on every distro.

Comment: Incidentally, I needed to do `(unset BROWSER; xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox-esr.desktop)` (I normally use `BROWSER=lynx`) because the mere presence of that environment variable made xdg-settings refuse to do its job. While `update-alternatives` is also a point worth looking at, this is the one I was looking for and that corresponds to “default browser” as the browsers themselves see; thanks!

Answer (score 19):

All preferences about default applications your user located in file "mimeapps.list". I am use Gnome 3 and Debian, so for me it is `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.

I you don`t know where is may be located this file, try command:

```
locate mimeapps.list
```

For override default a web browser you need, at least, change values in category **[Default Applications]**

- x-scheme-handler/http
- text/html
- application/xhtml_xml
- image/webp
- x-scheme-handler/https
- x-scheme-handler/ftp
- x-scheme-handler/https
- x-scheme-handler/ftp

and in category **[Added Associations]**

- text/html
- text/xml
- application/xhtml_xml
- image/webp
- x-scheme-handler/https
- x-scheme-handler/ftp

For *Opera* the file `~/.config/mimeapps.list` must contains:

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/http=opera-browser.desktop
text/html=opera-browser.desktop
text/xml=opera-browser.desktop
application/xhtml_xml=opera-browser.desktop
image/webp=opera-browser.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=opera-browser.desktop
x-scheme-handler/ftp=opera-browser.desktop

[Added Associations]
text/html=opera-browser.desktop;
text/xml=opera-browser.desktop;
application/xhtml_xml=opera-browser.desktop;
image/webp=opera-browser.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/https=opera-browser.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/ftp=opera-browser.desktop;
```

Try it (must be open in Opera, if it installed)

```
xdg-open somehtmlfile.html
```

For *Chrome* the file ~/.config/mimeapps.list must contains:

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/http=google-chrome.desktop
text/html=google-chrome.desktop
text/xml=google-chrome.desktop
application/xhtml_xml=google-chrome.desktop
image/webp=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/ftp=google-chrome.desktop

[Added Associations]
text/html=google-chrome.desktop;
text/xml=google-chrome.desktop;
application/xhtml_xml=google-chrome.desktop;
image/webp=google-chrome.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/https=google-chrome.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/ftp=google-chrome.desktop;
```

Try it (must be open in Chrome, if it installed)

```
xdg-open somehtmlfile.html
```

And so on (Firefox, or something else).

You need only override desire mimetypes. But I recommend use GUI for it. It will be reduce amount of errors.

It is actual for me system and will be change from system to system, from desktop environment to desktop environment, and so on.

**Testing environment**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie
$ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$s gnome-session --version
gnome-session 3.14.0
```

Comment: In Xubuntu/XFCE, "GUI" means the `Settings > MIME Type Editor`.

Comment: I tried all the options above and this one solved control+clicking links in the terminal window

Answer (score 2):

System -> Control Center -> Preferred Applications

for ubuntu with MATE DESKTOP

Answer (score 1):

You can also change your default browser in the relevant browser settings - e.g.

**Firefox:**
[image: Preferences, tick 'Always check if Firefox is your default browser']

**Chromium:**
[image: Settings, click 'Make chrome default browser']

Comment: This is not working for me on 15.04

Comment: Didn't work for me for Vivaldi on 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from some of the comments above, I would suggest following the top answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/96081). 
It involves changing the *mimeapps/url* schemes of your current user.

I had to use that solution to make linux **Skype** behave normally. Most other applications would use *x-www-browser* or *gnome-www-browser* but I guess they do have a point of using the *URL Schemes*; sometimes it has more sense.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I thought this still answered the question for **Skype** for which as far as I know, the changes in the *top* answer don't influence how skype chooses the default application in **all** conditions. The answer is here to help users in case the first one does not. If this can be done by responding with comments to the first answer I will do just that. :) Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: Got your point, Adrian – just sitting in the same boat. Still, that didn't solve it for me. What solved it, was [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/367820/68291). But that might be due to the fact I'm using LXDE as desktop.

Answer (score 0):

- open brave browser then click top right corner icon then click `Settings`.
- you will see something like:
  [image]

+Now set as default browser button(3rd link).