# How to set Google Chrome as the default browser?

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, default-browser

How can I set Google Chrome as the default browser? If I set it in the browser settings, nothing happens. The browser says it's default, but in preferred applications in Gnome, there's only Firefox to choose from. Clicking any link i.e in Thunderbird opens a blank Firefox window, not with the link embedded. Can I set the  default browser in dconf2 or any configuration file?

Comment: Have you tried setting the default browser via `System Info`->`Default Applications`->`Web`?

Answer (score 69):

Assuming you are using Unity, click on the dash button in the launcher and search for 'System info'. Then, open 'System info' and move to 'Default applications' section. Then, click on the dropdown list next to Web. There, select 'Google Chrome' and it will be selected as the default web browser for your system.

[image]

Comment: Oh well! I was looking for this myself! They really got away with hiding and removing settings in this Ubuntu version, I thought **Default Applications** was removed!

In *Gnome Shell* you can access it through **System Settings > System Info > Default Applications**.

Comment: why is chrome not in the list for me ?

Comment: I have this, still Firefox opens as default.

Answer (score 51):

You should have in the `~/.config/mimeapps.list` file the following lines:

```
text/html=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/http=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/about=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/unknown=google-chrome.desktop
```

Make sure these lines are under either the `[Default Applications]` or `[Added Associations]` section.

And of course, you need `google-chrome` installed such that `google-chrome.desktop` is either located at `/usr/share/applications/`, `/usr/local/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/`.

Comment: Thanks! In Gnome settings Firefox was declared to be my browser of choice (as I wanted), but only after fixing this file Firefox really became my default browser.

Answer (score 40):

Alternatively, you can do the following instead of editing `mimeapps.list`:

```
xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop text/html
xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop x-scheme-handler/http
xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop x-scheme-handler/https
xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop x-scheme-handler/about
```

To check the current settings, you can use:

```
xdg-mime query default text/html
xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/http
xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/https
xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/about
```

Comment: Thank! Setting these to exo-web-browser.desktop helped me a lot.

Comment: Works for applications that are not available in the drop-down list of the settings dialog

Comment: this works when I click on a url in a terminal or within vim/mutt

Comment: Does not work: xdg-mime default chromium.desktop text/html, xdg-mime query default text/html -> firefox.desktop

Answer (score 14):

There are [a number of places](http://blog.codef00.com/2011/02/18/the-default-browser-on-linux-debacle/) an application might figure out which browser to launch and unfortunately there is no established standard. If the other answers don't work for you (as was the case for me with Skype) you could try:

- the `$BROWSER` environment variable
- `/usr/bin/x-www-browser`, which is configured via the alternatives mechanism: `sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser` (which is what Skype is launching it seems)

Comment: I have the following when I enter this command. Any idea what the difference between "auto mode" and "manual mode" is?
There are 2 choices for the alternative x-www-browser (providing /usr/bin/x-www-browser).

  Selection    Path                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/firefox                40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       manual mode

Comment: From the manpage:
Each link group is, at any given time, in one of two modes: automatic or manual.  When a group is in automatic mode, the alternatives  system  will
automatically  decide,  as  packages  are installed and removed, whether and how to update the links.  In manual mode, the alternatives system will
retain the choice of the administrator and avoid changing the links (except when something is broken).

Comment: how to change  `$BROWSER`?

Comment: In your current shell, you can `export BROWSER=/path/to/browser`. If you want to persist this change, add it to e.g. `~/.profile`.

Answer (score 5):

There are also the /etc/alternatives/ where you have links:

- gnome-www-browser ->
- x-www-browser ->

In my case Lotus Notes opened wrong browser using the link gnome-www-browser.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 18.04 and later select *Settings* -> *Details* -> *Default Applications*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For Kubuntu 20.04 with Plasma, you can do the following:

1. Open the "*Application Launcher*"
2. Type "*Default Applications*" into the searchbox
3. You should see a system settings module with a star as an icon. It should actually says "*Default Applications*". Select it and open it
4. Select the option "*Web Browser*" and from there just choose "*Google Chrome*" as the default app for opening `http` and `https` URLs
5. Click "*Apply*" in order to save the settings

See the preview at the following screenshot of the [default applications utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuxX7.png).

Alternatively, you can do this from the "*System Settings > Applications (under Personalization) > Default Applications*"