# How to open local file or url in Tor browser?

Tags: tor

I've just installed Tor-browser and I want to make it default system browser but can't because it can't do simple things like opening local files or urls.

When I enter in terminal:

```
torbrowser-launcher duck.com
```

It opens the browser on the default page and ignore my url, but `torbrowser-launcher --help` say:

```
usage: torbrowser-launcher [-h] [--settings] [url [url ...]]

positional arguments:
  url         URL to load
```

I've tried `torbrowser-launcher url duck.com` but it also doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Tor Browser as default browser?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542372/set-tor-browser-as-default-browser)

Comment: No, my question is not how to set default browser. I want to know how to open files and urls from terminal or file manager. I can do this easily with Firefox or Chrome, but not with Tor.

Answer (score 0):

Give up the absolute path for "start-tor-browser" with **--detach** followed by URL

Something like;

'../tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser' **--detach** [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Comment: torbrowser-launcher: error: unrecognized arguments: --detach