# I want to change the browser used for opening links

Tags: google-chrome, browser, system-settings

I use Chrome for most everything.

Sometimes in external applications I click links to web resources. 
The operating system responds by firing up firefox, which then opens a tab for displaying the link.

I'd prefer that the link opens in Chrome.

I've set my default browser to Chrome.
This doesn't change the behaviour of the operating systems behaviour.

Comment: How did you set Chrome as the default browser? Same as [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/96199/301745)?

Comment: Check what is in Settings > Details > Default Applications.

Comment: 'Settings > Details > Default Applications' has the setting for the default browser. I set this to Chrome many reboots ago. It has no effect on how ubuntu opens links on my system.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/96081/527764) by [Severo Raz](https://askubuntu.com/users/567/severo-raz) to this question:

[How to set Google Chrome as the default browser?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96080/how-to-set-google-chrome-as-the-default-browser)

> You should have in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`
>   file the following lines:
>
> ```
> text/html=google-chrome.desktop
> x-scheme-handler/http=google-chrome.desktop
> x-scheme-handler/https=google-chrome.desktop
> x-scheme-handler/about=google-chrome.desktop
> x-scheme-handler/unknown=google-chrome.desktop
> ```
>
> Make sure these lines are under either the `[Default Applications]` or
>   `[Added Associations]` section.
>
> And of course, you need google-chrome installed such that
>   google-chrome.desktop is either located at `/usr/share/applications/`,
>   `/usr/local/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/`.

Comment: Just to confirm: those entries already exist in mimeapps, and I do have chrome installed and aliased to google-chrome