# How do I stop Chrome hijacking link intent?

Tags: google-chrome, mate

I'm using Ubuntu Mate 15.04 and ever since I installed Google Chrome it's hijacked every clickable link.

Firefox is set as my **default browser** but links from apps are opening in Chrome. Default was set in both Firefox and System preferences.

How do I stop this and revert back to links opening in Firefox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change my default browser?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/79305/how-do-i-change-my-default-browser) Should work almose the same with the MATE desktop.